# Rewrite directory location to a php file nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I'm having difficulty converting this .htaccess in /thumb directory to nginx to work.

.htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* ../thumb.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

What I tried:

```
location /thumb {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /thumb.php;
}

location /thumb {
    index thumb.php;
    rewrite ^/thumb/(.*)$ /thumb.php;
}
```

These won't work.

edited: I think I found the problem but I'm still puzzle on the solutions.
I made a small echo php file to test, all result that does not end in extension seem to work. Any url that end with any extension will return a 404.

http://www.example.com/thumb  work
http://www.example.com/thumb/jsdlfjfds  work
http://www.example.com/thumb/jsdlfjfds/sfjlkdfjldf  work
http://www.example.com/thumb/asldkjfls.png  not work
http://www.example.com/thumb/zxcvmfds/asldkjfls.jpg  not work

How do I rewrite full url, including all extension to /thumb.php? I always thought this regex mean full url with extension ^(.*)$?

thumb.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "These won't work" is insufficient to diagnose a problem with an otherwise reasonable looking configuration. Error and access logs? Desired and actual behaviour? Does `/thumb.php` fire up when accessed directly?

Comment: Edited with more example.

Comment: Do you have any `location` blocks which match the *file extensions* that do not work?

Comment: You're right it was another location. I know that location exist but didn't think it would have any affect, but for some reason it does, I'm not sure why.

location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
                expires max;
        }

Why would those affect my rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

There was another location that match the file extensions and it seem the two can't co-exist. They need to be put in a nested location.

```
location /thumb {
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|webp|svg|ai|eps)$ {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
                expires max;
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /thumb.php;
        }
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /thumb.php;
}
```